# How to change the width of the bar in bar chart in react-charts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart

I am implementing the bar chart and I am stuck with the following thing:

Sometimes, the width of the bar is too much, it looks like the graph is broken as it overlaps with the axes. What approach should I follow to keep the bar width in control according to data?

Here is the data sample and how the graph looks like. I have added the code sandbox also.

```
const dataOne = [
    {
      label: Translate.string('Events'),
      data: [[2018, 3], [2019, 2], [2020, 1]],
    },
  ];
```

[image: Screenshot from 2020-03-09 16-11-37]

[image: Edit epic-bohr-05txo]

Let me know if I have to provide any other information. I have posted this issue [here also](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-charts/issues/58).

Comment: well, obviously the library is not that good if there isn't support for width.., checked there code and could find anything relevant  after a quick search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving deep in the library, I found that there is a bug in calculating `CSS` transforms for `rect` elements for `bar`.

I was not able to found a full-proof way of solving this but I came up with a workaround (adding null values in the start and end of the data) which is working well for my use case and may help someone else to solve their problem so thought of adding the workaround as an answer.

```
import moment from "moment";
import React from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-charts";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const dataone = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        label: "Event",
        data: [
          [moment(2010, "YYYY"), null],
          [moment(2011, "YYYY"), 3],
          [moment(2012, "YYYY"), 2],
          [moment(2013, "YYYY"), 1],
          [moment(2015, "YYYY"), 3],
          [moment(2016, "YYYY"), null]
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );
  const options = {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          barPercentage: 0.4
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  const series = { type: "bar" };
  const axes = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      { primary: true, type: "time", position: "bottom" },
      { type: "linear", position: "left" }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "600px",
          height: "300px"
        }}
      >
        <Chart
          data={dataone}
          options={options}
          axes={axes}
          series={series}
          tooltip
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react charts bar chart]

Comment: setting the `barPercentage` property worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is actually stored in `scales.xAxes` ("Options for xAxes" table).

So you just have to edit your chart this way :

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.4
        }]
    }
}
```

And [this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html) will be good for some references but particularly see [this too](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness)

Comment: I am using [react-charts](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-charts/) not **chartjs**